# Multiplatform use of Bazel: OSX+homebrew and linux+{rpm,dpkg}

Tags: homebrew, bazel, multiplatform

How do I use `bazel` to build from the same source base on different platforms with external dependencies?

- On OSX it should use the installed homebrew package
- On Debianish it should use a corresponding dpkg
- On Redhatish it should use a corresponding rpm
- etc.

There also could be platform dependent flags in the autoconf style that should be passed to the compiler.

I mostly care of C and C++

Answer (score 0):

There is a feature in Bazel called `select()` that lets users toggle the values of build rule attributes at different platforms with external dependencies

This can be used, for example, for a multiplatform library that automatically chooses the appropriate implementation for the architecture, or for a feature-configurable binary that can be customized at build time.
For example:

```
sh_binary(
    name = "my_target",
    srcs = ["my_target.sh"],
    hdrs = ["my_target.h"],
    deps = select({
        "<condition>": ["<source>: dependency",],
       ...
       ...
       ...
    }),
)
```

This is also documented in Bazel [select and dependencies](https://bazel.build/docs/configurable-attributes#select-and-dependencies).